# NoClassDefFoundError with HikariCP

Tags: java, maven, hikaricp

When trying to compile HikariCP with my application, I'm getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig` error.

It does build into the .jar file, but it seems like at runtime the application can't find it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.MyApp.App</groupId>
    <artifactId>App</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>me.MyApp.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



</project>
```

I thought adding the Assembly plugin would fix it, but it didn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: EDIT: "Extracting" the output from within Intellij seems to of worked, but why? Why isn't there a maven only setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have this:

```
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>me.MyApp.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
```

...I would assume that this means that your `Class-Path` entry in MANIFEST.MF is just a "." (i.e. the current directory only - no JAR files).

I'd suggest you change it to:

```
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>me.MyApp.App</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
```

[Reference Link](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html)